# Why doesn't meta.webapps have the ability to edit/ add OpenIDs ?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-accounts, openid

I want to add a second openID, my profile page doesn't have that option ? Is this by design ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your profile data is taken from the main webapps site. Edit it on webapps.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: KInda weird. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

There is no user profile here, your profile is on the parent site -- edit it there.