# If profile data is from the "main" site, indicate that on the user page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-profiles

Was reading [this question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197) about changing your OpenID for meta and it stated that the profile is through the "main" site (webapps.stackexhange.com) and not meta. This is great, but after viewing my profile on meta, I think my profile should indicate something like *click here to edit your profile on webapps.stackexchange.com* or similar.

Answer (score 2):

This has now been implemented.

*(Answer needed to remove this question from our unanswered list)*.